# Psql command run script insert into PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

I have script `student.sql` and I would like to run this script to database by Java.

I use like below

```java
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("psql -d test3 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres -f student.sql", new String[]{"PGPASSWORD","root"});

if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
    System.out.println("Success!");
} else {
    System.out.println("error");
}
```

that no error and no response from `process.waitFor()`

My Question.

How to run import file to database(postgres) ?

Thank brother.

Comment: Are you aware that you can create a database table from java code using JDBC?

Comment: Yes But I want use `Process` by command to create database. @DavidBuck